# jqueryvalidate - adjusting focus on invalid

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

Website has a static menu bar across the top of the page and then the form is below that in the main body.  Using jqueryvalidate, my error messages are shown just under the form input element.  My problem is that when it focuses on the first invalid element the input box and upper label are hidden behind the static menu bar.  Is there a way to adjust the focus on invalid so that it focuses higher on the form?

```
errorElement: "div",
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
     var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {                    
         validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
        }
    },
```

Here's the bottom of the input box hidden behind the static menu/header.

[image]

All of the input elements are contained in a div, and if there is an <h6 class="note"> present the error message hides that and then shows it again when the field is valid.

```
<div class="3u">
  <input type="text" name="dob"/>
  <h6 class="note">Date of birth</h6>
</div>
```

I was thinking about how I could change the focus to the parent <div> but so far haven't gotten that to work.

Comment: Seems like your problem has very little to do with the jQuery Validate plugin, and everything to do with how you've structured your HTML & CSS.

Comment: *"My problem is that when it focuses on the first invalid element the input box and upper label are hidden behind the static menu bar."* ~ your problem description is incredibly unclear.  Can you create a jsFiddle demo?  The focus simply puts the cursor's focus on the first invalid element, so how could this cause it to suddenly appear behind something else?  Seems like you just need to restructure your page so there's enough space between your menu bar and the form, rather than tinkering with the default behavior.  What happens when you simply set the `focusInvalid` option to `false`?

Comment: *"I was thinking about how I could change the focus to the parent <div> but so far haven't gotten that to work."* ~ I think you need to re-examine your definition of "focus".  The "focus" feature of this plugin simply puts the cursor on the first invalid field.  What good will it do to focus a `div`, when `div` elements are not validated and do not accept user input, so they are irrelevant with respect to this plugin.